# Уведомления в трее (WinAPI C++)

Tags: c++, winapi

Нужно при определённых событиях в программе показывать над её иконкой в трее соответствующие уведомления. Компилятор MinGW не понимает параметра `NIF_INFO`. Структура определена так:

```
NOTIFYICONDATA TrayData;
TrayData.cbSize = sizeof(TrayData);
TrayData.hWnd = HWindow;
TrayData.uID = 1;
TrayData.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP;
TrayData.uCallbackMessage = WM_TRAYICON; // #define WM_TRAYICON (WM_USER + 1)
TrayData.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MAINICON));
strcpy(TrayData.szTip, App_Name.c_str());
```

Что писать в функциях для вывода сообщения в трее?

Comment: может все-таки поставить VisualStudio и WinSDK? раз уж вы все-равно под Windows разрабатываете?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

добрый день!
почитайте [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb773352(v=vs.85).aspx)
из него становиться ясно, что перед #include "windows.h"
нужно объявить #define _WIN32_IE 0x0500 и всё заработает ;)

только что сам проверил на mingw - сработало

кстати выдержка из shellapi.h из состава mingw:

```
#if (_WIN32_IE >= 0x0500)
#define NIF_INFO    0x00000010
#endif
```

Comment: Да, спасибо! Уже разобрался. Сделал #define _WIN32_IE 0x501. Также изменил NOTIFYICONDATA на NOTIFYICONDATAW. В первом случае строчки с szInfo и NIF_INFO Netbeans подчёркивал красным, хотя собирал нормально, а при использовании W-версии всё шикарно и без ошибок.

Answer (score 4):

Если не понимает, то что мешает определить эту константу

```
#define NIF_INFO (0x00000010)
```

Или взять другой компилятор/хедеры?

Comment: Спасибо за идею с #define, попробую.